# apt-get BADSIG signature gpg error

Tags: apt, amazon-ec2

I am trying to do an `apt-get update` in one ec2 instance and I get the following error:

```
W: GPG error: http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates
Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG
40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key
<ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

I tried to `apt-get clean` and remove `/var/lib/apt/lists` and then re create it but this did not work.
Tried adding signature with

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
```

But this did not work either. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like OP has gone through that duplicate link already... and the answers given there doesn't work for him...